How do I limit the rotation of an texture to a fixed rotation?
My goal is to randomly rotate the texture in 90 degrees increments, i want to use the map range node, with steps, so in the future i can change it to for example 45° steps.


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? And probably a stupid question, but why the Vector Rotate node is plugged in the Location input of the Mapping node ?
